# POSTGRES check if a provided value is present in the column of type array

Tags: postgresql, hapi

I am trying to check whether a value if present in the column, which is of type array(column_name text[]).
As a server i am using hapi and trying to check the same from hapi through query.

Query which i have written is(query is not working):

```
where: { column_name: { $in: { provided_value} }}
```

The column contains the values as:

```
{1234, 3456}
```

The values are of type text.

Can someone please help me to identify the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: array or json ? and what's your exact question ?

Comment: `where provided_value = any(array_column)`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan The column type is array. The values are shown in {1234, 2345} format in the database table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the answer. I tried it some time back and it works. The only thing is i want to use it as a sequelize query. Could you please provide me the same. I am trying since long but unable to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize does not support this use of `ANY`, they seem to only support its use like `IN`.
Instead, you should try the contains operator (`@>`):

```
import {Op} from "sequelize";

MyModel.findAll({
  where: {
    column_name: {
      [Op.contains]: [provided_value]
    }
  }
});
```

This will generate something like

```
SELECT * FROM "MyModel" WHERE column_name @> '{"provided_value"}';
```