# POSTGRES sequelize ANY operator query

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, hapi

I want to sequelize the following query:

```
SELECT * from TABLE_NAME where '928120' = any(COLUMN_NAME);
```

The above query gives the desired result. Although i want to use it as a sequelize query to use it in my node(hapi) application.

Can someone please help me on the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536125

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That was related to query. And this is related to sequelizing the same. I wanted both these to be separated one so that other's, in future, can related to each of these individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query.

```
Entity.findAll({
    where: {
       column: { [Op.any]: `{${Array}}` }
    }
})

Ex:
return await User.findAll({
   where: {
     id: { [Op.any]: `{${[1, 2]}}` }
   },
   raw: true
})
```